# Error: "Method 'rows' of object '_Global' failed

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

For some reason even though I am referring to the oSheet variable it is returning the error as if I am referring to a global variable?

PS I am trying to populate a combobox in word with a contractor names from an excel sheet I have created. I searched in google and here, none of the solutions have worked for me unfortunately. I believe the error lies within the For Each statement.

```
  Sub Macro3()

Dim oXL As Excel.Application
Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim oRng As Excel.Range
Dim ExcelWasNotRunning As Boolean
Dim WorkbookToWorkOn As String

'specify the workbook to work on
WorkbookToWorkOn = "C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\KTC\VBA Experiment\Excel Files\testExcel.xlsx"

'If Excel is running, get a handle on it; otherwise start a new instance of Excel
On Error Resume Next
Set oXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

If Err Then
   ExcelWasNotRunning = True
   Set oXL = New Excel.Application
End If

On Error GoTo Err_Handler

'If you want Excel to be visible, you could add the line: oXL.Visible = True here; but your code will run faster if you don't make it visible

'Open the workbook
Set oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=WorkbookToWorkOn)


'Process each of the spreadsheets in the workbook
For Each oSheet In oXL.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
   'put guts of your code here
   'get next sheet


 If oSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row = 1 Then
   lastRow = 2
   Else
   lastRow = oSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   End If

  ' For i = 2 To lastRow
  ' workZonerForm.contracterCMB.AddItem oSheet.Cells(i, 1)
  ' Next i


   MsgBox lastRow

Next oSheet

If ExcelWasNotRunning Then
  oXL.Quit
End If

'Make sure you release object references.
Set oRng = Nothing
Set oSheet = Nothing
Set oWB = Nothing
Set oXL = Nothing

'quit
Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
   MsgBox WorkbookToWorkOn & " caused a problem. " & Err.Description, vbCritical, _
           "Error: " & Err.Number
   If ExcelWasNotRunning Then
       oXL.Quit
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `oSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1)` should be `oSheet.Cells(oSheet.Rows.Count, 1)` (as you use a few lines below)

Comment: YowE3k that is an accident I tried to use that for both of them it did not work

Comment: Did you just change the code in the question to make it incorrect in both locations?  If so, you will now need to change both locations of `oSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1)` to be `oSheet.Cells(oSheet.Rows.Count, 1)`.

Comment: And, FWIW, I would change `oXL.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` to be `oWB.Worksheets`.  Although the newly opened workbook should be the active workbook in the `oXL` instance of Excel, you have already set `oWB` to be a reference to that workbook, so you may as well use that anyway.

Comment: YowE3k, sorry for the confusion, the solution you are offering, I have tried and it threw the same error as just (Rows.Count, 1)

Comment: When it crashes, go to the Immediate Window and type in some commands (a) `?oSheet.Name` (should return the sheet name - make sure it is what you expect) (b) `?oSheet.Rows.Count` (supposedly will crash, but will be good to prove it does) (c) `?oWB.Name` (should give the workbook name) (d) `?oXL.ActiveWorkbook.Name` (should also give the workbook name).  Unfortunately I am about to leave work, and won't be home to continue this discussion for another 90 minutes.  Maybe someone else will assist while I am away from the keyboard.

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: Hi Guys thanks for your vigilance in assisting me. YowE3K I will try that, however I had this working as a test to just get the data for the first cell (I used the name of my dog) and I was able to display it in word through a message box. Initially I got the same error except with 'Cells' replacing 'Rows' which I rectified by using oSheet instead of 'ActiveSheet'. Please understand I am a novice, thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Zac im almost certain it is one of the lines in the if statement, within the for each workbook